# C++ Unexpected behavior with remove_if

Tags: c++, string, stl-algorithm

I am trying to use `std::remove_if` to remove spaces from a simple string, but I am getting weird results. Could someone help me figure out what's going on?

The Code is:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <string>

int main(int argc, char * argv[])
{
    std::string test = "a b";
    std::remove_if(test.begin(), test.end(), isspace);
    std::cout << "test : " << test << std::endl; 

    return 0;
}
```

I expect this to simply print out:

```
test : ab
```

but instead I get

```
test : abb
```

Trying with another string, I get:

Input: "a bcde uv xy"

Output: "abcdeuvxy xy"

It seems like it duplicating the last "word", but sometimes adds a space. How can I just get it to remove all spaces without doing weird stuff?

Comment: Take a look at [the first  note](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/isspace), it can help you with your problem.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

[`std::remove_if`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/remove) performs *removing* by shifting elements; the *removed* elements won't be *erased* from the container in fact. STL algorithms don't have such privilege; only containers can remove their elements.

(emphasis mine)

> **Removing is done by shifting (by means of move assignment) the
>   elements in the range in such a way that the elements that are not to
>   be removed appear in the beginning of the range**. Relative order of the
>   elements that remain is preserved and **the *physical* size of the
>   container is unchanged**. Iterators pointing to an element between the
>   new *logical* end and the *physical* end of the range are still
>   dereferenceable, but **the elements themselves have unspecified values**
>   (as per [*MoveAssignable*](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/named_req/MoveAssignable) post-condition). **A call to remove is typically
>   followed by a call to a container's erase method, which erases the
>   unspecified values and reduces the *physical* size of the container to
>   match its new *logical* size**.

You can `erase` the *removed* elements afterward (which is known as *erase–remove idiom*).

```
test.erase(std::remove_if(test.begin(), test.end(), isspace), test.end());
```